# Why setting videoRotation on AVCaptureConnection causes torch to turn off

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm working on a camera app that records video, for that purpose, the app has to take into account the fact that the user might rotate his phone before starting a capture. So, before starting the recording, im getting the `AVCaptureConnection` associated with my active `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and setting connection's `videoOrientation` depending on device orientation. However, if the torch is on, this causes the torch to turn off.

Here's the code snippet for setting orientation on the connection:

```
let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        let connection = videoDataOutput?.connection(with: .video)
        var rotationAngle: CGFloat
        var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation
        switch orientation {
        case .portrait:
            rotationAngle = 0
            videoOrientation = .portrait
        case .landscapeLeft:
            rotationAngle = 90
            videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeRight:
            rotationAngle = -90
            videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            rotationAngle = 180
            videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            rotationAngle = 0
            videoOrientation = .portrait
        }
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            if connection?.isVideoRotationAngleSupported(rotationAngle) ?? false {
                connection?.videoRotationAngle = rotationAngle
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported ?? false {
                connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
            }
        }
```

The native camera and other camera apps dont seem to have such issue, I'm also on iOS 16.6.1
Any help would be greatly appreciated!